# AS3 Bitmaps and Filters

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap

I feel like I'm missing something here, so hopefully this question will be answered quickly.

I'm beginning to use blitting to make my program more efficient due to the number of objects moving on the screen. And right now I'm testing out how to do the differently; I'm up to filters.

I'm trying to apply a simple glow filter using applyFilter();
The problems are:

a) It only works if I define the rectangle as bitmapData.generateFilterRect() which isn't an issue except

b) It ignores this and applies the filter while cropping the entire image. If you notice, only the top left corner is actually glowing, the rest is just cut off.

Original Grass Tile 
[image: Original Grass Tile]

Grass Tile with Glow Filter applied 
[image: Grass Tile with Glow Filter applied]

What am I missing here?

```
public function applyFilter(filter:*):void{
    bitmapData.applyFilter(bitmapData, bitmapData.generateFilterRect(new Rectangle(0,0, 100, 100), filter), new Point(0,0), filter); 
}

grass.applyFilter(new GlowFilter(0x000000));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) if you're trying to get performance?

Comment: I like writing my own engines to learn more.

Comment: Using Starling isn't really taking away your ability to write your own engine though, it covers basically the same amount of stuff that using the native `flash.display.*` APIs does for you (just the rendering part).

Comment: I'm nearly finished with this project. I'm just up optimizing it a bit. It would be a real pain to change how all the images work at this point.

Answer (score 1):

This might be your problem:

> After a filter is applied, **the resulting image can be larger than the input image**. For example, if you use a BlurFilter class to blur a source rectangle of (50,50,100,100) and a destination point of (10,10), the area that changes in the destination image is larger than (10,10,60,60) because of the blurring. This happens internally during the applyFilter() call.
>
> [Source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#applyFilter()).

It sounds like you need to calculate the new image size and draw that to the screen, rather than the original size.

Comment: Yes, that's why I use BitmapData.generateFilterRect().  I even tried expanding the Rectangle parameter to give it extra room, but it still crops.

Comment: Can you add the code you use to draw the result image to the screen? Because it looks like you're just missing something there to account for the new larger size that will include the cropped portion. The examples in your question are the same size.

Comment: All the data is put on the screen somewhere else. This is what applies the filter.

Comment: Yes, but when you apply the filter your image will become larger than it was originally. If the logic to put it on the screen elsewhere isn't aware of the dimension change then you will get a cropped image as a result.

Comment: The screen's rect is the size of the stage, shouldn't that not be an issue?

Comment: Ok, i solved it. The issue was that I should have directly applied the filter to the screen's data, not the individual image data. Thanks for that hint :D